# Boolean product and semplify

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean, xor

I have a question for you.

For example I have this boolean expression:

**(((A AND B) OR C) AND D) AND ((K AND Z) OR (J AND H)) AND Y**

THis is just an example but I can have a lot of expression like this, I've to write an algo in JavaScript for make this expression simple and representable through a json.

The basic idea is to use boolean product like that:

**(A AND B) OR C  = (A OR C) AND (B OR C)**

But how can I write something automatic for do that?

Thank you.

Comment: `(A AND B) OR C = (A OR C) AND (B OR C)` which of these two is representable by JSON? And how? Which part of your first example expression is *not* representable by JSON?

Comment: Thank for reply. Both the expressions I've to rappresent by JSON. The user should create the configuration with a front-end app and I've to convert all.

Comment: Then I don't understand the question. *How* should they be represented? And why is the first one not representable?

Comment: *"I've to write an algo in JavaScript for make this expression simple and representable through a json"* This could be as simple as `{"expression": "(((A and B) ..."}` or you could actually have a parser generate an AST for you. There are parser generators that take a grammar of a language and generate the parser for you. If you don't even know how to represent this information in JSON then you first have to think about that. We can't tell you how to represent it because we don't know how the data is going to be used. You have to look at your requirements and design the format accordingly.

Comment: I've to rapresent like the library of Sebastian!
Now I'm trying thank you all for reply, I will let u know the result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check out an existing library like [riichard/boolean-parser-js](https://github.com/riichard/boolean-parser-js) on GitHub.

Comment: Thank you bro, I think that this is the answer, I try and let you know!